# Passing in a new value to each key using Python's `dict.fromkeys`

Tags: python

How can I get around this limitation:

```
>>> test_dict = dict.fromkeys(['k1', 'k2'], dict())
>>> test_dict['k1']['sub-k1'] = 'apples'
>>> test_dict
{'k2': {'sub-k1': 'apples'}, 'k1': {'sub-k1': 'apples'}}
```

I want each of the keys `k1` and `k2` to have a new dictionary instance, not the same one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then don't give them the same instance of the object.

```
test_dict = dict((x, dict()) for x in ['k1', 'k2'])
```

Comment: Apparently there is no way to pass an expression to `dict.fromkeys`. Thanks.